# how to set different onclicklisteners on same button click?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-button

I am implementing a timer in android with one text view and one button for start/stop.

How do I set register different events on clicklistener of the same button, such that when it is clicked the first time it will start a timer and when clicked a second time it will stop the timer and report the time between events?
I am implementing a timer in android with one text view and one button for start/stop.

How do I set register different events on clicklistener of the same button, such that when it is clicked the first time it will start a timer and when clicked a second time it will stop the timer and report the time between events?

**Edit1**

what i did is,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_depth);
    findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);

}
boolean showingFirst = true;
public void generate(View view){

    if(showingFirst){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        showingFirst = false;
    }else{
        long difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        showingFirst = true;
        TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        myText.setText(String.valueOf(difference));
    }

}
```

but since long starttime is started in if when the control enters else loop it shows
*cannot resolve symbol 'startTime'*

please help and special thanks to eliamyro

Comment: you can use condition inside onClickListener, don't need different onClick.

Comment: could you please refer me to link describing that or give a little code snippet. Thank you

Comment: I believe that @NiranjPatel is referring to a simple `if` condition in the listener. I should be simple enough to use that if you have some prior Java knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a global boolean `isStart` and start or stop the timer depending on the value of the `isStart`.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isStart) {
            // Stop timer
            isStart = false;
        } else {
            // Start timer
            isStart = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(btn.getText().toString().equals("Start")){
            btn.setText("Stop");
            // start timer
        }else{
            btn.setText("Start");
            // stop timer
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

on click (start/stop) button start the timer according to your code and return a value to button and when you click again that flag value can be used to create a if condition for stop as well as start

Answer (score 0):

As you are starting and stopping a `Timer` with your button you can just check if the timer is running or not. I would suggest extending a `TimerTask` for that use case (I took that code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290308/5052976)):

```
public class YourTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private boolean isRunning = false;

    @Overrides
    public void run() {
        this.isRunning = true;
        //rest of run logic here...
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return this.isRunning;
    }
}
```

Then in your `onClickListener` you can just check if your timer is running or not:

```
startStopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (yourTimer.isRunning()) {
            stopTimer();
        } else {
            startTimer();
        }
    }
});
```